# factors of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Let $f,g,h$ be polynomials over a field $F$.

$\forall t \in F$, 
$$f(x) = g(x)h(x) \iff f(x+t) = g(x+t)h(x+t)$$

The reverse direction is trivial. The forward is also obvious but I'm just wondering if there is a way to rigorously show it.

Comment: Can't you just substitute $x=u+t$?

Answer (score 0):

Both directions follow from substitution! No more work is necessary than that.

Comment: @Phantom Does this answer your question?